# C# Microsoft Graph Expand Parameter throws Exception

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am in the process of getting Microsoft Graph running with the official C# library (5.20.0 installed via nuget).

I would like to retrieve list items from a sharepoint list of contacts.

I have already tried with the Graph explorer and found out that I have to append the parameter "?expand=columns" to the end of the URL to get all the properties that are important for me.

The query URL looks like this:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[SITE_ID]/lists/[LIST_ID]/items?expand=columns](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%5BSITE_ID%5D/lists/%5BLIST_ID%5D/items?expand=columns)

Now I would like to implement this with the C# API.
For this I have looked at the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http#expand-parameter.

My code looks like this:

```
var result = await graphClient.Sites["SITE_ID"].Lists["LIST_ID"].Items.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) => {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "columns" };
            });
```

I can't see any difference to the documentation.

However, I always get the following exception thrown:

`"Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError" in mscorlib.dll`

Unfortunately there is no meaningful message to the excpetion either.

If I remove the expand parameter I get data. The connection works and is not the problem.

I noticed that in the documentation there is a $ in front of the Expand parameter.
If I reproduce this in the Graph Explorer, I also get an error.

Is there a solution how I can get the data from my query without this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace `columns` by a real child relation avalaible on your resource. `$` is mandatory before `expand` in ODATA specifications

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[SITE_ID]/lists/[LIST_ID]/items?$expand=child
```

If you want to select all properties from an item, I would suggest to take a look at ODATA `$select`

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

If I replace "columns" with "fields" the query works!
I was just confused that it worked in Graph Explorer with "columns" and not in my C# code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that expanding `columns` requires `expand` query parameter without `$` but SDK creates `expand` query parameter with `$`.

Until it's fixed in SDK, you need to use a workaround

```
var request = graphClient.Sites["SITE_ID"]
                 .Lists["LIST_ID"]
                 .Items
                 .ToGetRequestInformation((requestConfiguration) => 
        {
            requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "columns" };
        });

request.UrlTemplate = request.UrlTemplate.Replace("%24expand", "expand");
request.QueryParameters["expand"] = request.QueryParameters["%24expand"];
request.QueryParameters.Remove("%24expand");

await graphClient.RequestAdapter.SendAsync(request, ListCollectionResponse.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue);
```

But if you expand `fields` then the `expand` query parameter can be with `$`, so no workaround needed.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[SITE_ID]/lists/[LIST_ID]/items?$expand=fields
```

but

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/[SITE_ID]/lists/[LIST_ID]/items?expand=columns
```